# Why can some urls contain "fake" directories?

Tags: php, ios, wallet

Currently, I'm trying to set up updates for passes that are added to the Wallet app on iOS.

One thing that is interesting is that having the url `https://example.com/index.php/var1/var2` still works and index.php is still run. Is there a reason why this url format works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.htaccess`/`mod_rewrite` is the reason why it's working.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Having this rules inside a file named `.htaccess` in the root folder of your website, will make the path `/var1/var2` available inside `$_GET['path']`

Comment: I'm kind of confused with your solution. You say that `mod_rewrite` is the reason, yet the code you have provided is just for allowing the trailing info to be turned into $_GET. Would it have to do with `AcceptPathInfo` in Apache?

Comment: Nope. Read the documentation. You enable `mod_rewrite` in apache conf, with that "switched on" you can put a `.htaccess` file into your root folder to enable the functionality with your rules.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for explaining!